# Get direct children of custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, php

I've googled extensively and tried my best, but I just can't get the first level children of the custom taxonomy in the code below to work! It only displays the parent level. What I am trying to achieve is the following:

```
Level 1  <--- at the moment, it only displays this level
  Level 2  <-- I want to display this level too
    Level 3  <-- but NOT this level
```

This is my code so far:

```
function my_dropdown_categories( $taxonomy, $current_selected = '', $include = null ) {
// Get all terms of the chosen taxonomy
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array('orderby' => 'name'));

// our content variable
$list_of_terms = '<select id="location" class="selectboxSingle" name="location">';

if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) foreach($terms as $term){

// If include array set, exclude unless in array.
if ( is_array( $include ) && ! in_array( $term->slug, $include ) ) continue;

$select = ($current_selected == $term->slug) ? "selected" : ""; // Note: ==

if ($term->parent == 0 ) {

    // get children of current parent.
    // $tchildren = get_term_children($term->term_id, $taxonomy); <- gets ALL children

    $uchildren =get_terms( $taxonomy, array('hide_empty' => 0, 'parent' => $term->term_id ));

    $children = array();
    foreach ($uchildren as $child) {
        $cterm = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy );
        // If include array set, exclude unless in array.
        if ( is_array( $include ) && ! in_array( $cterm->slug, $include ) ) continue;
        $children[$cterm->name] = $cterm;
    }
    ksort($children);

    // PARENT TERM      
    if ($term->count > 0) {
      $list_of_terms .= '<option class ="group-result" value="'.$term->slug.'" '.$select.'>' . $term->name .' </option>';
    } else {
      $list_of_terms .= '<option value="'.$term->slug.'" '.$select.'>'. $term->name .' </option>';
    };

    // now the CHILDREN.
    foreach($children as $child) {
       $select = ($current_selected == $child->slug) ? "selected" : ""; // Note: child, not cterm
       $list_of_terms .= '<option class="result-sub" value="'.$child->slug.'" '.$select.'>'. $child->name.' </option>';
    } //end foreach
  }
}

$list_of_terms .= '</select>';

return $list_of_terms;
}
```

If someone can help me with this beast, you'll be my freaken hero!

**EDIT** (more info based on Pieter's answer):

*This is what is being output (all parents):*

Parent 1

--Parent 1

--Parent 2

--Parent 3

--Parent 4

Parent 2

--Parent 2

--Parent 1

--Parent 3

etc

Comment: Your `// OPTGROUP FOR PARENTS` code is freaking me out, are you using braces or not? Seems like some horrible to read mix.  My advice would be to get all the `{}` in and update the question.  Also test it after converting to the explicit form to see if this fixes some small problem.

Comment: Jeepers! Not exactly sure what happened there! Prime evidence of a day that was too long? Anyways, I've updated my question:) - and tested it, still the same problem.

Comment: This is not your complete code, what is `$include`? What if only `continue` happens in that loop? Also, is `'parent' => 1` intentional or you are assuming it to be a boolean value (0/1). Shouldn't it be `'parent' => $term->id`?

Comment: @SaurabhShukla I've updated the question with more code and your suggestion. The $tchildren function that I've commented out was the originally function that was working, but getting ALL the terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two issues here, one is a performance issue, the other is big issue that should return a pile of errors if you enable debug

The performance issue here is your first instance where you are getting the terms. It seems that your goal here is to get only top level terms, yet you get all. I would just add `'parent' => 0` to the arguments to get only top level terms. You can then drop the condition where you check `if ( $term->parent == 0 )` because all terms will be top level terms which will all have `0` as term parent, so this condition will always return true

Your big issue is with this code, and I don't understand your logic here

```
    $uchildren =get_terms( $taxonomy, array('hide_empty' => 0, 'parent' => $term->term_id ));

    $children = array();
    foreach ($uchildren as $child) {
        $cterm = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy );
        // If include array set, exclude unless in array.
        if ( is_array( $include ) && ! in_array( $cterm->slug, $include ) ) continue;
        $children[$cterm->name] = $cterm;
    }
    ksort($children);
```

You are correct in getting your direct term children, so your declaration of `$uchildren` is fine. From there everything goes haywire

- Why are you using [`get_term_by()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) here. `$child` already holds the term properties as you have used `get_terms()` to retrieve the terms.
- You are not just using `get_term_by()` wrongly here, but your arguments are invalid, and you are passing a complete object to it as well. You should consult the codex for proper use of this function. All in all, that section should be removed from your code

That section should look something like this

```
    $uchildren =get_terms( $taxonomy, array('hide_empty' => 0, 'parent' => $term->term_id ));

    $children = array();
    foreach ($uchildren as $child) {
        if ( is_array( $include ) && ! in_array( $child->slug, $include ) ) continue;
        $children[$child->name] = $child;
    }
    ksort($children);
```

### EDIT

Here is a full working code with a couple of bugs fixed. Please see my comments in code for the updates

```
function my_dropdown_categories( $taxonomy, $current_selected = '', $include = null ) 
{
    /*
     * Declare your variable first. Without this, your code has a bug if no terms are found
     */
    $list_of_terms = '';

    /**
    * Get all parent terms. Note we use 'parent' => 0 to only get top level terms
    *
    * @see get_terms
    * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms
    */
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array( 'orderby' => 'name', 'parent' => 0 ) );

    /*
    * Use curlies here to enclose your statement. Also, check whether or not you have terms
    */
    if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {

        /*
        * Moved this section inside your if statement. We don't want to display anything on empty terms
        */
        $list_of_terms .= '<select id="location" class="selectboxSingle" name="location">';

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

            // If include array set, exclude unless in array.
            if ( is_array( $include ) && ! in_array( $term->slug, $include ) ) continue;

            $select = ($current_selected == $term->slug) ? "selected" : ""; // Note: ==

            /*
             * Use the parent term term id as parent to get direct children of the term
             * Use child_of if you need to get all descendants of a term
             */
            $uchildren = get_terms( $taxonomy, array('hide_empty' => 0, 'parent' => $term->term_id ));

            $children = array();
            foreach ($uchildren as $child) {
                // If include array set, exclude unless in array.
                if ( is_array( $include ) && ! in_array( $child->slug, $include ) ) continue;
                $children[$child->name] = $child;
            }
            ksort($children);

            // PARENT TERM      
            if ($term->count > 0) {
                $list_of_terms .= '<option class ="group-result" value="'.$term->slug.'" '.$select.'>' . $term->name .' </option>';
            } else {
                $list_of_terms .= '<option value="'.$term->slug.'" '.$select.'>'. $term->name .' </option>';
            };

            // now the CHILDREN.
            foreach($children as $child) {
                $select = ($current_selected == $child->slug) ? "selected" : ""; // Note: child, not cterm
                $list_of_terms .= '<option class="result-sub" value="'.$child->slug.'" '.$select.'>'. $child->name.' </option>';
            } //end foreach

        }

        /*
        * Moved this section inside your if statement. We don't want to display anything on empty terms
        */
        $list_of_terms .= '</select>';

    }
    return $list_of_terms;
}
```

Comment: Pieter, I can't thank you enough. Seriously:) Thanks SOOOO much for all your help, I really do appreciate it a lot! have a great evening, and thank you x 100000 :))

Comment: My pleasure, glad everything worked out for you. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
$uchildren =get_terms( 'category', array('hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => $term->term_id ));

$children = array();
foreach ($uchildren as $child) {
    $cterm = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy );
    // If include array set, exclude unless in array.
    if ( is_array( $include ) && ! in_array( $cterm->slug, $include ) ) continue;
    $children[$cterm->name] = $cterm;
}
```

This line

```
$cterm = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy );
```

assumes that $child will be an id (and an integer), whereas:

```
foreach ($uchildren as $child) {
```

[gives us an object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms#Return_Values)

This also is the reason why this doesn't work as you want:

```
if ( is_array( $include ) && ! in_array( $cterm->slug, $include ) ) continue;
```

**From here is junk that I had posted but good sense prevailed,  till...**

Let's do the fun part:

```
var_dump($term):
```

Notice the type of each property:

```
object(stdClass)(9) {
    ...
    ["parent"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ...
}
```

See the `parent`. It's a string. I know, logically it should be an integer, but it's a string. It sucks, right!

So, your `if ($term->parent == 0 ) {` condition is not getting satisfied. Try this instead:

```
if ( empty( $term->parent ) ) {
```

**here**

Comment: Thanks for that explanation:) That's very strange that it's a string...oh well. 
Unfortunately I'm still stuck - the code snippet after `//now the CHILDREN` is not working, unless I comment out `if ( is_array( $include ) && ! in_array( $cterm->slug, $include ) ) continue;`, but then it retrieves **ALL** the children of the parent

Comment: The condition should work, `==` tests if a given value is the same as the one it is tested againsts, `'0' == 0` will return true. Note, they are the same, not identical. `'0' === 0` will return false, as `===` test if two values are identical, and `'0'` and `0` is not identical, but the same

Comment: @PieterGoosen I know, but that's how it's working here. I'll edit the answer to remove the misleading 'never be satisfied'.

Comment: This is pure php. The condition can only fail if the value which is being tested is not `0`. If a term's parent is `0`, your condition will return true. Something else in the code is failing

Comment: @Guit4eva, you should check the `$include` array. Also, even if it is just `continue;` use braces.

Comment: Thanks, I've added braces:) I don't know if this helps with solving, but if I use `foreach ($tchildren as $child) {`, it shows all the children (and grandchildren). If I use `foreach ($uchildren as $child) {`, it shows no children (ie, the code after `//now the CHILDREN` doesn't work.

Comment: My earlier answer was a piece of junk. I should probably sleep more. I have edited it. I ascribed some other change to something else.